# rails_admin "Last Used" column is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have configured the `rails_admin` gem in my RoR app. In the table that is displayed in the dashboard page, the "Last Used" column is empty. I can't find any configuration options related to this in the [wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki). Is there any configuration that I have to do for this value to be displayed?

**Edit** : I found that rails_admin expects an "updated_at" column in each table, and I understand that it is rails convention to have an "updated_at" column. But mine is a legacy database into which I am integrating rails_admin. So in each table I have columns like "created_on" etc. So is there any provision for me to "specify" the column which should be used by rails_admin to display the "Last Used" information?

Comment: Is that column actually populated for each record? Is that column an association? We need much more information here.